# URL .htaccess Strip after unknown directory

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

Basically, I haven't tried much but also cannot find an answer for my query. I need to reduce the URL:

```
https://mycustomurl.com/directory1/directory2/xxxxxxx/sms
```

To

```
https://mycustomurl.com/directory2/xxxxxxx
```

Where directory names are known and the x's represent an unknown random number representing a generated content page's ID. I was hoping to do this in .htaccess.

Comment: `.htaccess` is just a common name of a config file and fundamentally has nothing to do with your question..  Look up how to properly use `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: Would you like me to rewrite the question as it remains the same? In one of my .htaccess files in whatever directory it needs to be in, I would like a statement/s that can do what I'm asking. I can't really find anything that lets me do what I have asked. Regex statements are foreign to me, please don't simply say "Go Learn" as that's exactly what I'm here for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have `mod_rewrite` enabled in your Apache config, you can put the following in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/directory1/directory2/([0-9]+)/sms$ /directory2/$1
```

If directory1 and directory2 are not fixed names, you could try something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/[^/]+/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/sms$ /$1/$2
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. Works a charm.

Comment: Great. Glad to be of help.